# grub2 removed "quiet splash" options are ignored

Tags: 12.04, grub2

After installing Ubuntu 12.04 I have edited **/etc/default/grub** and changed the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

then run

```
# update-grub2
```

Upon reboot I am not seeing the kernel messages printed to screen as expected. I only see a blank purple screen.

What else needs to be configured for grub to display kernel messages upon boot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this happen when the framebuffer text mode isn't properly supported. Uncomment the line:

```
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

(remove the `#`) and run `update-grub` as superuser again. So it should read:

```
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

If you expect to see GRUB2 itself, make sure to adjust the timeouts.

Note: this will give you the classic 80x25 text mode instead of the framebuffer text mode with higher resolution.

Comment: 80x25 text mode works for now. Thanks.